# Clubbing similar codes

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula

I need your help on the following i have a column A with batch numbers as below

```
COL A
SFF123
SFF123+124
Sff123+124
SFF124+125
SFF125+126+127
SFF127+128
SFF128
SFF128+GHI345
GHI345+346
GHI346
```

I need only the unique values in COL B as follows

```
COL B
SFF123
SFF124
SFF125
SFF126
SFF127
SFF128
GHI345
GHI346
```

In other words if there is only single value in the corresponding row, the formula should return that value, If there are two or more values then it should return the code that was not repeated in the previous row.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is it safe to assume that SFF123+124 means SFF123 AND SFF124? Are you looking to excel only, or are you open to VBA?

Comment: @L.Dutch Yes, Your assumption is true and I am open to Vba aswell

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you only the unique strings, but spread onto 3 columns.

[image]

Set the following formulas:

In B2 `=IF(MID(A2,7,1)<>"",1,0)` will check if your string has more than 6 chars

In C2 `=IF(B2=1,IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A2,8,3)),"text"),"")` will check if the exceeding 6 chars are only numbers or text and numbers

In D2 `=IF(MID(A2,11,1)<>"",1,0)` will check if your string has more than 10 chars

In E2 `=MID(A2,1,6)` will return the first string

In F2 `=IF(C2="text",MID(A2,8,6),IF(ISNUMBER(C2),CONCATENATE(MID(A2,1,3),TEXT(C2,0)),""))` will return the second string

In G2 `=IF(AND(D2=1,C2<>"text"),CONCATENATE(MID(A2,1,3),TEXT(MID(A2,12,3),0)),"")` will return the third string

In H2 `=IF(COUNTIF(E$2:G2,E2)=1,E2,"")` and extend it to I and J. This will show all the unique strings.

Comment: Thanks for your effort @L,Dutch. But how can i achieve the desired result based on your analysis above

Comment: I had tried to set a formula that concatenates the char and the triplet for all the first time appearance. Since I don't know how your real data look like, all my attempts were too example dependent.

Comment: I can share my data with you.I have close to 750 entries. Is there any other way i can share the file with you?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot work on all your data. In my spare time I can further look into your question to improve my answer.

Comment: please check the edited answer. Now you should get the unique strings.